# How does glass affect taking solar spectra?

Tags: spectroscopy

In this case I'm using a CCD camera mounted telescope pointed at the clouds to take solar spectra and was wondering how the telescope being pointed at the clouds through a double gazing (two layer) glass window would affect the spectra, if at all?

Comment: Depends on a variety of factors such as how dirty your windows are, how free of imperfections in the glass they are, how flat they are, etc. The clouds could also potentially mess up your spectrum just as much if not more by contributing a lot of their own lines/noise to the spectrum.

Comment: @zephyr  those are secondary problems.

Answer (score 2):

you'll need to find the spectral transmissivity of each piece of glass.  Most likely they all block UV and large sections of the IR bands.  Further,  unless you've removed the internal IR filter, your camera won't record any IR.  CCDs also cut off in the blue, so no UV will be recorded.

BTW, how are you separating the wavelengths at the camera?  Typically one uses a (expensive) grating spectrometer.

Comment: This is a university telescope for physics students experiments. I don't know the more precise details of the telescope but at the highest dispersion setting we measured the radial velocity of the sun in the order of 10s of kilometres per second which is a good 10-100 times the actual velocity.